# dependency injection in a multi modul java project

Tags: java, spring, maven

My Maven project consists of 6 Maven projects. The service classes are all in different projects. I would like to use dependency injection for the service interfaces in the controller. My problem is that the configuration class can not scan the other projects with the componentScan. How do you scan all projects for services and components?

The configuration class:

```
package org.Configverwaltung;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "org.Spielverwaltung", "org.Deckverwaltung", "org.Kartenverwaltung", "org.Spielerverwaltung"})
    public class Config {
    }
```

---

```
Part of the first controller:

import org.Deckverwaltung.Deck;
import org.Deckverwaltung.DeckService;
import org.Deckverwaltung.DeckServiceInterface;
import org.Kartenverwaltung.KartenServiceInterface;
import org.Kartenverwaltung.Kartenservice;
import org.Spielerverwaltung.Spieler;
import org.Spielerverwaltung.SpielerServiceInterface;
import org.UserInterface.SpielerView;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class SpielErzeugenController {

    //Dependency Injection
    @Autowired
    public SpielerServiceInterface spielerService;//Interface
    public SpielerView spielerView;
    public KartenServiceInterface kartenservice;
    public DeckServiceInterface deckService;
    public List<Spieler> spielerListe;
    public Deck nachziehstapel;
    public Deck ablagestapel;
    public SpieloptionenInterface spieloptionen;


    public SpielErzeugenController(){
        this. spielerView = spielerView;
        this.spielerService = spielerService;
        this.kartenservice = kartenservice;
        this.deckService = deckService;
    }
```

Main class:

```
@Service
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //SPIELERZEUGEN

        SpielErzeugenController spielErzeugenController = new SpielErzeugenController();
        spielErzeugenController.run();

        //SPIEL SPIELEN
        GameSpielenController gameController = new GameSpielenController(spielErzeugenController);
        gameController.run();

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use mvn modules to bind modules together?

Comment: first you should not use public attributes you should private attributes instead and you should not use `@Autowired`.. you should simply define the parts you would like inject into the constructor as parameters...Furthermore your Application with `main´ should not being defined as `@Service` use `@SpringBootApplication` annotation instead. The main method should look different... You should check some examples of spring boot example projects...

Comment: I always thought that you only use SpringBootApplication if you program a web application. I don't want an web application.